# Strange behaviour of names in lists

Tags: r

I assign names to a list of elements. The first one gets a string directly, the second one gets a name from an expression using paste. Why has the name in both cases a different format? Why has variable `st` below length=1 ?

```
rr<- list(5,9)
names(rr)[1]<- "xxx"
st<- paste("yy",toString(2))
names(rr)[2]<- st
rr
$xxx
[1] 5

$`yy 2`
[1] 9

rr$xxx
[1] 5

rr$yy2
NULL

is.character("xxx")
[1] TRUE
is.character(st)
[1] TRUE
length(st)
[1] 1
```

Comment: Which part do you find strange ? `st` is just one string which is `"yy 2"` hence `length` is 1. The backquotes in name is because the name has got spaces in it and is not in standard format. To select it by name you need to do `rr$\`yy 2\``

Comment: Or make things easy for yourself and use names without spaces in them, e.g. `st <- paste0("yy", 2)`

Answer (score 0):

By default [`paste`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/paste) has a single space separator. 
If you want your variable to be called `yy2`, you can create `st` either using the function `paste0` or by explicitly using `sep=''` as the argument for `paste`:

```
#like this:
st<- paste("yy",toString(2), sep='')
# or this: 
st<- paste0("yy",toString(2))
```

Hope this helps.